# Undefined method `map' while running Capybara test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara

I'm running a feature test using Capybara, but keep getting this error:

```
 Failure/Error: select(@architect2.name, from: 'architect')

 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
   Did you mean?  tap
 # ./spec/features/reassign_team_spec.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/support/database_cleaner_spec.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/support/database_cleaner_spec.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rspec-retry-0.6.1/lib/rspec/retry.rb:123:in `block in run'
 # /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rspec-retry-0.6.1/lib/rspec/retry.rb:110:in `loop'
 # /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rspec-retry-0.6.1/lib/rspec/retry.rb:110:in `run'
 # /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rspec-retry-0.6.1/lib/rspec_ext/rspec_ext.rb:12:in `run_with_retry'
 # /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/rspec-retry-0.6.1/lib/rspec/retry.rb:37:in `block (2 levels) in setup'
```

The test is:

```
click_button('Switch')
select(@architect2.name, from: 'architect')
select(@supervisor2.name, from: 'supervisor')
```

And the code in the view is:

```
<%= select_tag :architect, options_for_select(User.is_architect.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] }, params[:architect]), {:prompt => 'All', :class => "form-control", :required => true } %>
<%= select_tag :supervisor, options_for_select(User.is_supervisor.collect{ |u| [u.name, u.id] }, params[:supervisor]), prompt: 'All', class: "form-control" %>
```

Using pry I could check that the `User.is_architect` list exists. Trying to do the select command throws this:

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::ReassignTeams>)> select(@architect2.name,from: 'architect')
NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  tap
from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionview-5.2.3/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb:364:in `options_for_select'
```

Everything works just fine when testing manually. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please add the stack trace from the error to your queestion so we can see where the error is actually coming from

Comment: @ThomasWalpole added the stack trace :)

Comment: Assuming reassign_team_spec.rb:30 is `select(@architect2.name, from: 'architect')` then you'll need to enable a more verbose backtrace so I can see what line in Capybara or whatever that is calling the error is coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem and it turned out that I was including `ActionView::TestCase::Behavior` which was interfering with things. I was able to work around this by adding a `page` qualifier to the `select` statement, i.e. `page.select @architect2.name, from: 'architect'`.

It turns out I didn't even need `ActionView::TestCase::Behavior` for this particular test, once I removed it I could remove `page.` and all was well.

So, it may be worth reviewing included modules, and adding the `page.` qualifier to make sure something else isn't getting in the way.

Comment: I couldn't find unnecessary modules, but the page qualifier worked! Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad I could help @Zavitoski!

Answer (score 0):

Have you trying clearing up assets
This would be helpfull if  you have changed something on front end
It will clear your assets and compile them from start.
This might help
rake assets:clean
rake assets:clobber
rake assets:precompile

Comment: Actually whenever something is changed on front end then we need to recompile whole front end and if we don't do it then front end will never pick up those changes and will rely upon previous front end.